# film producer sound mixing for first time by self, please help

Tags: film-sound-design

Hey,
Please help me if you're experienced with sound mixing. I am an aspiring filmmaker and just locked picture on my 25 minute film. I produced it but I'm also editing and sound mixing. I'm on to sound mixing. What are the dB audio levels I want to keep my dialogue between? I saw a youtube video that said -8dB is where you want to keep it but as I'm getting more experience, that sounds like the maximum level I should take it to. My second question, what are good audio levels for the soundtrack?

BTW great forum board, thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

Petr,

Welcome! Sounds like you have a big project ahead of you. Please note that it is worth searching the forum for your questions, as this very same question has come up before in discussion here in various formats. For instance:

[TV Broadcast Levels](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/618/tv-broadcast-levels) 
[Dia always the same level?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/dia-always-the-same-level) 
[Tips for mixing dialogue](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/tips-for-mixing-dialogue)

There are so many standards thrown around on the internet for what level you should mix to, but ultimately you need to experiment and learn for yourself. Experienced mixers go off of what they hear in front of them, and base many of their level-setting decisions on previous mixing experiences.

Ultimately, calibration of and time spent with your monitoring system is your most important ally when you mix. If you set up your speakers so that the levels you mix to are directly corollated to the levels you hear then you are free to make creative choices without worrying if your dialog level is hitting __dB. Even more, if you calibrate your system based on the destination of your film then you give yourself a huge foot forward. If your movie will be shown on youtube, you will calibrate your system differently than if the movie will be shown in a theater, which is different than broadcast TV, DVD, etc... Watch this movie for more detailed instructions on how to set up your speakers:

http://vimeo.com/22735507

I also must recommend finding an experienced sound designer to take a look at your film. This is why we exist! Even if it's just a 1- or 2-hour session, getting a demonstration on the mixing process might make a huge difference for you when you sit down to mix. It could be well worth the time and money.

Best of luck!
~Matt

Answer (score -1):

Good day to everyone,

Well, before you have to know what type of sound you already had in your sound.

So you first have to have good sense in your auditions and a few experiences on the pre-mix. For me first you have to listen to your fillm without the mix and have a good feedback before the stage of the concrete mix.

Then what kind of speakers do you use ? What is your position in front of these speakers for your listening ? For the levels, -6db, -8db, depending on you, the film, and especially how was your sound taken ? IMPORTANT!

And finally your editing. I want to explain:

If you work your sound with as much discipline as possible in your mode of work ie your tracks are well arranged, your audios are well arranged and well controlled for volumes, no intru in Your tracks, your ADR, your SFX, your FOLEYS, your AMBIENCES, your MUDICS, and now you prepare well your BUS so that you have a precise control for each of your groups, so you will be able to live clearly your movie without worrying external ...

Pleasure, Roudie Rigaud MARCELIN